# Django: how to use Model properties as a string?

Tags: django, django-models

Supose I have such Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    var1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    var3 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    var4 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
    var100 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I must process all them in similar way, for example:

```
string = var1 if var1 else ''
string += var2 if var2 else ''
string += var3 if var3 else ''
string += var4 if var4 else ''
...
string += var100 if var100 else ''
```

In such way I will write 100 hundreds lines of code...

But maybe there is some way to process all of them in for statement, like:

```
string = ''
for i in range(1,101):
    string += var%s % i if var%s % i else '': #I know this is not right, but idea is understood
```

So I will write only 3 lines of code.

Is it possible do in Django?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to have so many fields your it would be wiser to use a foreign-key relation instead.

Comment: No, these fields are the same type: name, second name, favourite singer and so on.

Comment: IMHO You are trying to solve representation problems on the models, I have a similar problem for a set of properties, add a property get_values, return a string with render_to_string, and do all the if you like within a template.

Answer (score 2):

You could you try this:

```
#assuming this is on the Model
def get_values(self):
    ret = []
    for i in range(1, 101):
        field_name = "var%d" % i
        value = self._meta.get_field(field_name).value_from_object(self)
        if value:
            ret.append(value)

    return ''.join(ret)
```

Comment: So there is no trivial way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if there's a easier way. Maybe you could clarify us to exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to access the attributes in code

```
>>> class MyModel():
...    var1 = 'hello'
...    var2 = 'there'
...    var3 = 'simple'
...    var4 = 'example'
...
>>> foo = MyModel()
>>> getattr(foo,'var1')
'hello'
>>> number = 3
>>> getattr(foo,'var%s'%number)
'simple'
>>> for x in range(1,5):
...   print getattr(foo,'var%s' % x)
...
hello
there
simple
example
```